# Try to loop a variable

Tags: javascript, json, jenkins

I'm display some elements with JSON

I have to post the next job on each iteration knowing that the first one is toto

So for now I have: toto titi tata

And I can not see how to loop to see all the rest. I don't know how to my loop

```
    function getall() {
    ajaxGet(".../toto/api/json?pretty=true", recover);
}
getall(); 
function ajaxGet(url, callback) {
    ...
}

function recover(response){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var Data = Json.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {    
            console.log("toto");
            //toto
            console.log(group.name);    
            //titi
            ajaxGet2("..."+group.name+"/api/json?pretty=true", recover2);    

        });          
}

function ajaxGet2(url, callback) {
    ....
}

function recover2(response){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var Data = Json.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {        
            console.log(group.name);
            //tata       
    });       
}
```

DownStreamProject show the next job for example in my case :

- toto shows titi
- titi shows tata

and know i need to do a loop for each job and have next job like this:

- tata shows exm1
- exm1 shows exm2
- and continue ...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit dirty, not OOP, but should be functional. Pass the group name to getall to construct the URL.
Recover will save the new group name to the globalgroupname variable.
Then call getall in a loop while group name is something.

```
global.globalgroupname = "toto"; // start
let prevgroupname;

// Assume the chain ends when groupname is null or blank
while (globalgroupname) {
    // Do something with groupname
    // ...
    // reset globalgroupname to exit if ajax call fails
    prevgroupname = globalgroupname;
    globalgroupname = null;
    // Get next globalgroupname
    getall(prevgroupname); 
}

function getall(groupname) {
    console.log(groupname);
    //toto
    ajaxGet(".../" + groupname + "/api/json?pretty=true", recover);
}

function ajaxGet(url, callback) {
    ...
}

function recover(response){
    var Json = JSON.parse(response);
    var Data = Json.downstreamProjects.map(function(group) {    
            console.log(group.name);    
            //titi
            // Save in global state
            globalgroupname = group.name;
        });          
}
```

Comment: I'm using Node JS, so the equivalent of window is global. When I launch the script, it say me null...

Comment: global.groupe = null, I think this is the problem but don't know what can I do

Comment: Sorry, try again

Comment: Why are you sorry, it's ok ;) 
So now, I don't have null , it's good but only toto and titi are displayed...

Comment: I haven't used nodejs before. I think global should do the trick. Otherwise I'm out of ideas as of why it fails. Maybe the axax URL doesn't return tata but null?

Comment: Ok, but normaly in node js you use global with a dot (global.name), normaly the ajax URL does return value

Comment: I read that window.name the equivalent in node js was global.name

Comment: Unfortunatelygot always toto and titi :( 
Thanks for your help, I'm trying to find another solution